# Azure Synapse Copy Mapping adds (NULL)

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

I am trying to do manual mapping in Synapse Copy Activity. My Source is Json files from ADLS2 & Sink is SQLDB Table.

One of the column in Json is `Emp. Name` which need to mapped to `Emp_Name` so as per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#tabular-source-to-tabular-sink) I tried following dynamic contents

```
@json('{
    "translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "typeConversion": true,
        "mappings": [
            {
                "source": {
                    "name": "Emp. Name"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "Emp_Name"
                }
            }
        ],
        "collectionReference": "",
        "mapComplexValuesToString": true
    }
}')
```

and

```
@json('{
    "translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "mappings": [
            {
                "source": {
                    "path": "$[''ID'']"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "ID"
                }
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "path": "$[''Emp. Name'']"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "Emp_Name",
                    "type": "String"
                }
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "path": "$[''ChannelFormat'']"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "ChannelFormat"
                }
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "path": "$[''ChannelClassification'']"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "ChannelClassification"
                }
            }
        ],
        "collectionReference": "",
        "mapComplexValuesToString": true
    }
}')
```

But this adds `(NULL)` to the `Emp_Name` column in the table.

I also tried static mapping for all columns present in Json data file to table columns
[image]
But I got

```
"ErrorCode=UserErrorSchemaMappingCannotInferSinkColumnType,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Data type of column 'ChannelFormat' can't be inferred from 1st row of data, please specify its data type in mappings of copy activity or structure of DataSet.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'"
```

Source JSON file is list of json in it.

```
[  {"ID":"12345",.....,"Emp. Name":"ABC",...."ChannelFormat":null,"ChannelClassification":null},
   {"ID":"67890",.....,"Emp. Name":"XYZ",...."ChannelFormat":null,"ChannelClassification":null} ]
```

`Emp_Name` column is of data type `NVARCHAR(100)` in SQL DB table

I tried to import schema using Import Schema option but Interactive authoring is disabled, so I cant use this
[image]

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "ErrorCode=UserErrorSchemaMappingCannotInferSinkColumnType,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Data type of column 'ChannelFormat' can't be inferred from 1st row of data, please specify its data type in mappings of copy activity or structure of DataSet.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'"

The reason for the above error might be that there is no data type specified in the mapping for the columns.

follow the below steps to achieve your requirement.

This is my sample source json:

```
[
    {
        "ID":12345,
        "Emp. Name":"ABC",
        "ChannelFormat":null,
        "ChannelClassification":null
    },
    {
        "ID":67890,
        "Emp. Name":"XYZ",
        "ChannelFormat":null,
        "ChannelClassification":null
    }
]
```

Give the source and sink datasets in the copy activity and give the below mapping.

[image]

Click on **import schemas** and specify the target columns.

Now, your data will be copied without any errors.

[image]

**Update:**

You can build your mapping JSON like this and give it in the mapping dynamic content expression.

```
@json('{"type": "TabularTranslator","mappings": [{"source": {"path": "$[''ID'']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Id",
                                    "type": "Int32"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$[''Emp. Name'']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Emp_name",
                                    "type": "String"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$[''ChannelFormat'']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "ChannelFormat",
                                    "type": "String"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$[''ChannelClassification'']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "ChannelClassification",
                                    "type": "String"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "collectionReference": ""
                    }')
```

[image]

This mapping JSON built for the above sample JSON only. If you have more columns than this, you need to add more objects of source and sink keys to the `mappings` array.

Comment: Interactive authoring is disabled in my env, any other way I can specify the correct data type using dynamic contents ?

Comment: Check my update section. You can build your mapping like that as per your source JSON columns.

Comment: I tried mapping JSON, but for **Emp_name** column in table get value **(NULL)**

Comment: I tried with the mapping that you provided in the question and I got same null values for me as well. Your mapping json consists extra info like `{
    "translator": `. So, you need to remove that. Try with my mapping expression like above.